# React Router - Dynamic Single URL Returns White Page When Go Directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm pretty new on React Router. I'm studying on a blog app for practice. I've made a single post page. When i click "read more" button on homepage i can see details for post on single page at "**/post/$id**". But when i go to this url directly I'm getting blank white page. I don't know how to resolve that. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

**App.js**

```
import Home from "./Home";
import Single from "./Single";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/post/:postId" exact>
        <Single />
        </Route> 
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


function Home() {

  const [contents, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contents/",{
      method:'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token e02d408879bc0e2cc8bc6eb66cbd46c6af8e89ab'
      }
    })
    .then( resp => resp.json())
    .then( resp => setContent(resp))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))
  }, [])

  return (

    <> { contents.map(content =>  { return (
    
<Card>
        <Card.Title>{content.title}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>{content.description}</Card.Text>  
      <Link to={`/post/${content.id}`}>
        <Button variant="dark">Read More</Button>
      </Link>
   
</Card>
   
     ) })} </> ); }

export default Home;
```

**Single.js (post detail page)**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

function Single(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const path = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [contents, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contents/",{
      method:'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token e02d408879bc0e2cc8bc6eb66cbd46c6af8e89ab'
      }
    })
    .then( resp => resp.json())
    .then( resp => setContent(resp))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))
  }, [])

  return (

    <>
    
    { contents.filter(contents => contents.id == path).map(content => 
  
  {
      
    return (
    

         <>
            That's detail page for content {content.id}
         </>
   
    
         )})}</>);}

export default Single;
```

Comment: seems like contents is empty, can you check if its empty once you open the page directly?

Comment: I don’t think it’s about contents state. Because when I put a static text outside of the map function I can’t see this too. Somehow there is always white page. That’s very hard for solve :(

Comment: and what is in your console?

Comment: There is nothing... When I go to a URL directly like "/post/16" Also in the "Network" tab I can see fetch request to "/post/16/".